# How do I enforce a password complexity policy?

Tags: password, security, pam

I need to configure an Ubuntu server to follow a strict company password policy that specifies the following:

- at least one upper case
- at least one lower case
- at least one digit
- at least one special character

I've had a look around and all I have found is the [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/user-management.html) for specifying the password length; but, I have yet to find something that relates to specifying the content of the password regarding the above points.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update January 2023**: the library `pam_pwquality.so` has in many/most cases superceded the use of `pam_cracklib.so`. `pam_pwquality.so` should be backwards compatible with `pam_cracklib`. See [pam_pwquality.so man pages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/pam_pwquality.8.html?_fsi=XQL28PY9) for usage details & examples.

---

Password complexity is enforced by the [`pam_cracklib`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pam_cracklib.8) module.

In order to modify the password policy for your local machine, you will need to modify your `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file.

From a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), enter the following command:

```
sudo vi /etc/pam.d/common-password
```

Add the following line to the file (before `pam_unix.so` or whichever PAM module is used primarily for authentication, as can be seen from examples in the manpage) and save the file:

```
password requisite pam_cracklib.so ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 dcredit=-1  ocredit=-1
```

This statement implements the following password requirements:

- `dcredit` == digit
- `ucredit` == upper-case character
- `lcredit` ==lower-case character
- `ocredit` == other character (special characters, including `!` `,` `@` `#` `$` `%`)

This should satisfy your requirements.

You could also use the variables `minlength` and `retries` to further restrict the password requirements.

Here is another good example of modifying a password policy in this manner would be placing the following line in the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file:

```
password requisite pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=10 difok=3 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 dcredit=-1  ocredit=-1
```

This entry will set a maximum of three attempts at getting an acceptable password with a 10-character minimum length.

This sets the requirement for users to have a minimum of three characters different from the last password.

This will also fulfill the requirement of having the password contain at least one each of digit, lower-case character, and upper-case characters.

See also this article on [setting up stronger password policy rules in linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215022705/http://blog.subaquatic.net/archives/setting-up-stronger-password-policy-rules-in-linux).

Comment: Excellent answer! I'd add, regarding retries, that it's important to be careful when considering a policy to prevent users from logging on who have too many recent failed login attempts. This can lead to the viability of one of the simplest and most easily executed denial of service attacks on an account (try and fail to log in X number of times until the account is "locked out" and then the legitimate user cannot get in).

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks :)
One question though, it seems that the `root` user is able to ignore the password requirements... Is it possible to enforce this for the root user too?

Comment: @Valorin What part of the password requirements is the root user not respecting?

Comment: @maggotbrain Any of it, it throws a warning but still saves it, this was the password 'snare': http://paste.ubuntu.com/1543154/

Comment: @Valorin So, you've enabled the account called 'root' and can use this account with this password, correct? What warnings are you getting? Unfortunately, I don' t have a machine with an enabled root account to test this myself. It sounds like a bug, but need more info.

Comment: @maggotbrain Yeah, we have the root login enabled and working, but more to the point you can do it with `sudo` as well, so try: `sudo passwd your_username`

Comment: @Valorin I am not able to repro that issue. I can change user passwords and they respect the restricions that I place upon them. That said, I do not have the root user enabled. Take a look at the pam bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam.  You may want to [file a new bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) against this module.

Comment: @maggotbrain I'm running this on 10.04, so potentially something that has been fixed/changed in newer releases? I'll check the bugs list.

Comment: In 14.04 the module is `pam_unix.so`. Options will be same of that too?

Comment: It's 2020 and this answer is 7 years old now. I've seen several tutorials online saying that I should use pam_pwquality now instead of cracklib, without elaborating on why. Is cracklib still a good idea to use?

Comment: @9a3eedi It would be better if you asked a new question and referred to this Q&A as a reference to get answers.

Comment: I think you now should use `pam_pwquality.so`

Answer (score 1):

There's a fork of [pam_cracklib](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/pam_cracklib.8.html) by Tomas Mraz: [pam_pwquality](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man8/pam_pwquality.8.html) with slightly better options.

Add it with `apt install libpam-pwquality`
or passwd will complain:

> Module is unknown