# How to check password strength

Tags: command-line, password, text-processing

I wrote this script but `[:alnum:]` doesnt work. Anyone help?

```sh
echo -n "Enter a password : "
read password

LEN=$(echo ${#password})

if [ $LEN -lt 10 ]; then

       echo "$password is smaller than 10 characters"
else
     if ! [ -z `echo $password | tr -d "[:alnum:]"` ]; then
        echo "$password is a weak password"
     else
        echo "$password is a strong password"
     fi
fi
echo
```

Comment: @derHugo it doest work like that

Comment: works for me btw: `$ echo "Hallo123!" | tr -d '[:alnum:]' ` -> `!`

Comment: @derHugo if i use [:alpha:] it works. but when i use [:alnum:] doesnt work..!!

Comment: It's worth mentioning the excellent command line password generator `pwgen` here, see [`man pwgen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pwgen.1.html).

Comment: As https://xkcd.com/936/ teaches us, a password without anything besides even just `[:alpha:]` is **not necessarily weak**! It's *much* more difficult to say how weak or strong a password really is.

Comment: IMO see the link I gave you to enforce strong passwords. Use john the ripper , or similar, to test for weak passwords.

Comment: Available from the repos via [package `john`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/john), see https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper for instructions and the latest version.

Comment: Passwords don't have strength.  Password-generation methods have strength, and what you're trying to do is make an after-the-fact guess at the strength of the method used by looking at characteristics of the password it produced.  This only provides a benefit if your guess matches an attacker's guess.

Comment: All of these answers treat this as an XY problem.

Comment: you should use `read -s password` to hide the input

Answer (score 16):

If you really want to check password strengths, you should use `cracklib-check` from the `cracklib-runtime` package (should be installed by default):

```
$ echo foo | cracklib-check
foo: it is WAY too short
$ echo foobar | cracklib-check
foobar: it is based on a dictionary word
$ echo foobared | cracklib-check
foobared: it is based on a dictionary word
$ echo foobared123 | cracklib-check
foobared123: it is too simplistic/systematic
$ echo '!'foobared123 | cracklib-check
!foobared123: OK
```

Comment: `cracklib-check` doesn't seem to check (extensive) dictionaries of languages other than English: `subsidiary` → `dictionary word`, but German equivalent `subsidiär` → `OK`.

Comment: The [here string notation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) is very useful in this case: `cracklib-check <<< 1234`

Comment: @dessert probably depends on what dictionaries I have installed

Comment: If `cracklib-check` counts `!foobared123` as “OK” but `foobared123` as “simplistic”, it isn't trying hard enough. Adding one punctuation character is child's play for a password cracker. All `cracklib-check` really does is weed out *some* of the *extremely stupid* passwords, it doesn't really tell whether a password is strong.

Answer (score 14):

### Superficial problems

There are several problems with your script. It breaks if the password contains a number of special characters. Try entering input such as:

```
a space
two  spaces
a * star                            ← try this one in different directories
bbbbbbbbbb                          ← try this one in a directory containing a file called a
endswithabackslash\
```

**Read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767)**. All of it. Do not write any shell scripts that are remotely related to security until you understand all of it.

Oh, and `[:alnum:]` works perfectly. You probably intended to write `if [ -z …` or `if ! [ -n …` instead of `if ! [ -z …`.

### There's no such thing as the strength of a password

The idea of “password strength” is a myth. It's a myth that's spread by a lot of websites, but it's still a myth. There is no such thing as the strength of a password, [there is only the strength of a *password generation process*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37737/how-can-i-create-a-secure-password/37739#37739).

Having special characters in a password does not make it stronger. A password is a compromise between ease of memorizing and ease of cracking, and [special characters make passwords significantly harder to memorize but not significantly harder to crack](http://xkcd.com/936/), as analyzed in [this thread on Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) ([the short story](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6116), [the math](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6096), [some complements](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6155) — exercise: in [this wrong answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6103), which parts completely ignore the facts?). The idea that special characters make a password stronger is based on the assumption that people who write password crackers are idiots. Guess what: they aren't. There's money to be made by cracking passwords, so you can bet there are people who invest in doing it well.

### So how should I choose passwords then?

***Randomly***. If your method to choose a password doesn't include a source of randomness (with a computer, or rolling a dice if you like it old-school), it's no good.

[Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) is a popular choice, but any method that follows the [XKCD pattern](http://xkcd.com/936/) — pick multiple “words” at random from some dictionary — is good.

### A correct script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter a password : "
IFS= read -r password

LEN=${#password}

if [ "$LEN" -lt 10 ]; then
  printf "%s is smaller than 10 characters\n" "$password"
fi
if [ -z "$(printf %s "$password" | tr -d "[:alnum:]")" ]; then
  printf "%s only contains ASCII letters and digits\n" "$password"
else
  printf "%s contains characters other than ASCII letters and digits\n" "$password"
fi
```

Using `tr` in this way overcomplicates things. The shell is perfectly able to check whether a string contains characters among a certain set.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter a password : "
IFS= read -r password

LEN=${#password}

if [ "$LEN" -lt 10 ]; then
  printf "%s is smaller than 10 characters\n" "$password"
fi
case "$password" in
  *[![:alnum:]]*)
    printf "%s contains characters other than ASCII letters and digits\n" "$password";;
  *)
    printf "%s only contains ASCII letters and digits\n" "$password";;
esac
```

(Note that the statement about *ASCII* letters and digits is true for Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`, but in bash `[:alnum:]` includes all letters and digits in the current locale, not just the ASCII ones.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a good explanation, particularly why the XKCD pattern — pick multiple “words” at random from some dictionary — is good.   :-)

Comment: The Diceware web page seems moved to http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html

Answer (score 8):

Smells awfully like an XY problem to me. *Never, ever, write your own tools for working with passwords.* At least you aren't dealing with password storage here, but the first thing that comes to mind with your code is that I could enter an all-numeric password and have it considered "strong" (when in reality it would be a lot weaker than an all-alphabetic password). If you continue with this approach to security/password-handling, you're going to fall down sooner or later and it won't be pretty when it happens.

The correct solution is to use an external library or helper application to determine password strength (and perform other password-related tasks). Most Linux systems these days have PAM that can perform all authentication-related tasks for you in a secure manner (as a bonus you get support for other authentication methods besides passwords, depending on how the user's system is configured) and muru has already suggested a helper application that determines password strength.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/244115/how-do-i-enforce-a-password-complexity-policy

Comment: yeah, my old bank considers a 12 character limit and not allowing special characters "strong", but I suspect most experts disagree. using tools that get updated allows you to stay up with standards.

Comment: No application can determine the strength of a password, because there's no such thing. There is only the strength of a *password generation method*, and you can't tell the strength from one password.

Answer (score 1):

## If you want a good method to create passwords

See

[Password generator combining actual words](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976808/password-generator-combining-actual-words/977086#977086)

["Strong Passwords" or "Strength of a password generation process"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StrongPasswords)

## Your question: How to check password strength?

[How do I enforce a password complexity policy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244115/how-do-i-enforce-a-password-complexity-policy)

You can only check certain aspects of the password or use a specific tool for each method to create the password or a general brute force method (if the attacker does not know the method).

### Shellscript `pwdcheck` using `cracklib-check`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# setting variables

usage="Use 4 words chosen randomly, see this link:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase"

minlen=20  # can be modified here
short="is shorter than $minlen characters"
goodmix="is long enough"
badmix="is too short
$usage"
separator="-------"

# checking parameter

if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ] || [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
 echo "${0##*/} uses 'cracklib-check'"
 echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
 echo "Usage:   $0 CandidateContaining4DifferentWords"
 echo "Example: $0 At-least-$minlen-char"
 echo "         $0 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process'"
 echo "         $0 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!'"
 echo "         $0 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123'"
 echo "         $0 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words'"
 echo "$usage"
 exit
elif [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "$usage"
 echo "----------------------------------------------------------------"
 read -p "Enter a password : " password
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
 password="$1"
fi

# checking and installing if necessary

which cracklib-check > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
 read -p "Do you want to install 'cracklib-runtime' to get 'cracklib-check'? (y/N) " ans
 if [ "$ans" == "y" ]; then
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cracklib-runtime
 fi
fi

if [ ${#password} -lt $minlen ]; then
 result="$short"
else
 result="$goodmix"
 case "$password" in
  *[![:alnum:]]*)
     alnm="'$password' contains characters other than ASCII letters and digits";;
#     result="$badmix";;
  *)
    alnm="$password contains only ASCII letters and digits";;
 esac
fi

echo "Test 1 - size&mix: '$password' $result"
test ${#password} -lt $minlen || echo "$alnm"
if [ "$result" == "$badmix" ] || [ "$result" == "$short" ]; then
 total="is bad"
else
 total='is good'
fi

echo "$separator"
echo "Test 2 - lexicon: '$password'"
sed -e 's/[0-9]/123\n/g' -e 's/$//' -e 's/[§!@£$€#¤%/()=?*,;.:_-~ ]/123\n/g' -e 's/$/123/g' \
<<< "$password" | LANG=C cracklib-check |sed 's/123: /: /'| \
grep 'it is based on a dictionary word'
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
 echo 'no comment'
fi

echo "$separator"
echo "Test 3 - digital: '$password'"
sed -e 's/[[:alpha:]]//g' -e 's/[§!@£$€#¤%/()=?*,;.:_-~ ]//g' -e 's/$/xyz/' \
<<< "$password" | LANG=C cracklib-check |sed 's/xyz: /: /'| \
grep 'it is too simplistic/systematic'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 total='is bad'
else
 echo 'is good'
fi

echo "$separator"
echo "Test 4 - cracklib-check: '$password'"
LANG=C cracklib-check <<< "$password" | tee /dev/stderr | grep ': OK' > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 echo='is good'
else
 total='is bad'
fi

if [ "$total" == "is good" ]; then
 echo "$separator"
 ans=
 while [ "$ans" != "g" ] && [ "$ans" != "b" ]
 do
  read -p "Test 5 - manual: Is '$password' a good or bad password? (g/b) " ans
  if [ "$ans" == "g" ]; then
   echo 'is good'
  elif [ "$ans" == "b" ]; then
   total='is bad'
   echo "$total"
  fi
 done
fi

echo "$separator"
if [ "$total" == "is good" ]; then
 echo "Every test result for '$password' $total: No weakness found :-)"
else
 echo "Some test result for '$password' $total: Some weakness found :-("
fi
```

### Help text

Running in the current directory, a test directory. where you have the shellscript file,

```
$ ./pwdcheck -h
pwdcheck uses 'cracklib-check'
----------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:   ./pwdcheck CandidateContaining4DifferentWords
Example: ./pwdcheck At-least-20-char
         ./pwdcheck 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process'
         ./pwdcheck 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!'
         ./pwdcheck 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123'
         ./pwdcheck 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words'
Use 4 words chosen randomly, see this link:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase
```

### The cracklib program package

```
$ apt-cache policy cracklib-runtime 
cracklib-runtime:
  Installerad: 2.9.2-1ubuntu1
  Kandidat:    2.9.2-1ubuntu1
  Versionstabell:
 *** 2.9.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.9.2-1build2 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

## Testing the different examples from the help text

### Manual test important but use wisely

Your manual inspection and 'test' may be important to avoid really bad passwords,
but *if you used an automatic random method with a good reputation, you should rely
on it and avoid tampering with the result*, because you will probably make the password
easier to crack.

```
$ ./pwdcheck CandidateContaining4DifferentWords
Test 1 - size&mix: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords' is long enough
CandidateContaining4DifferentWords contains only ASCII letters and digits
-------
Test 2 - lexicon: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords'
no comment
-------
Test 3 - digital: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords'
is good
-------
Test 4 - cracklib-check: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords'
CandidateContaining4DifferentWords: OK
-------
Test 5 - manual: Is 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords' a good or bad password? (g/b) b
is bad
-------
Some test result for 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords' is bad: Some weakness found :-(
# comment: This password is published here!

##### Short password #####

$ ./pwdcheck At-least-20-char
Test 1 - size&mix: 'At-least-20-char' is shorter than 20 characters
-------
Test 2 - lexicon: 'At-least-20-char'
least: it is based on a dictionary word
char: it is based on a dictionary word
-------
Test 3 - digital: 'At-least-20-char'
is good
-------
Test 4 - cracklib-check: 'At-least-20-char'
At-least-20-char: OK
-------
Some test result for 'At-least-20-char' is bad: Some weakness found :-(

##### Reminder about random process #####

$ ./pwdcheck 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process'
Test 1 - size&mix: 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process' is long enough
'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process' contains characters other than ASCII letters and digits
-------
Test 2 - lexicon: 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process'
Should: it is based on a dictionary word
selected: it is based on a dictionary word
via: it is based on a dictionary word
random: it is based on a dictionary word
process: it is based on a dictionary word
-------
Test 3 - digital: 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process'
is good
-------
Test 4 - cracklib-check: 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process'
Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process: OK
-------
Test 5 - manual: Is 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process' a good or bad password? (g/b) g
is good
-------
Every test result for 'Should.be.selected.via.*random*.process' is good: No weakness found :-)
# comment: Do not use the password literally ;-)

##### Single quote the password, if you intend to use special characters   #####
##### Words are found by lexicon test (using cracklib-check), and accepted #####

$ ./pwdcheck 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!'
Test 1 - size&mix: 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!' is long enough
'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!' contains characters other than ASCII letters and digits
-------
Test 2 - lexicon: 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!'
Single: it is based on a dictionary word
quote: it is based on a dictionary word
for: it is based on a dictionary word
special: it is based on a dictionary word
character: it is based on a dictionary word
-------
Test 3 - digital: 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!'
is good
-------
Test 4 - cracklib-check: 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!'
Single-quote-for-1-special-character!: OK
-------
Test 5 - manual: Is 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!' a good or bad password? (g/b) b
is bad
-------
Some test result for 'Single-quote-for-1-special-character!' is bad: Some weakness found :-(

##### Showing how the digital test works (it uses cracklib-check) #####

$ ./pwdcheck 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123'
Test 1 - size&mix: 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123' is long enough
FindPatternByDigitalTest123 contains only ASCII letters and digits
-------
Test 2 - lexicon: 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123'
no comment
-------
Test 3 - digital: 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123'
123: it is too simplistic/systematic
-------
Test 4 - cracklib-check: 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123'
FindPatternByDigitalTest123: OK
-------
Some test result for 'FindPatternByDigitalTest123' is bad: Some weakness found :-(

##### Showing the lexicon test and the digital test #####

$ ./pwdcheck 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words'
Test 1 - size&mix: 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words' is long enough
Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words contains only ASCII letters and digits
-------
Test 2 - lexicon: 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words'
Provoke: it is based on a dictionary word
pattern: it is based on a dictionary word
search: it is based on a dictionary word
separating: it is based on a dictionary word
words: it is based on a dictionary word
-------
Test 3 - digital: 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words'
12345: it is too simplistic/systematic
-------
Test 4 - cracklib-check: 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words'
Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words: OK
-------
Some test result for 'Provoke1pattern2search3by4separating5words' is bad: Some weakness found :-(

##### Run interactively without any parameter #####

$ ./pwdcheck
Use 4 words chosen randomly, see this link:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase
----------------------------------------------------------------
Enter a password : CandidateContaining4DifferentWords
Test 1 - size&mix: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords' is long enough
CandidateContaining4DifferentWords contains only ASCII letters and digits
-------
Test 2 - lexicon: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords'
no comment
-------
Test 3 - digital: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords'
is good
-------
Test 4 - cracklib-check: 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords'
CandidateContaining4DifferentWords: OK
-------
Test 5 - manual: Is 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords' a good or bad password? (g/b) g
is good
-------
Every test result for 'CandidateContaining4DifferentWords' is good: No weakness found :-)
sudodus@xenial32 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/pwdstrength $
```

Comment: i run it and it always says strong password

Comment: I'll check and modify it ...

Comment: im trying too! waiting for your response!

Comment: @sudodus password shall be strong, if it does NOT ONLY contain `alnum`. Right now you only look if it has at least one `alnum`.

Comment: I think it is better now. We'll see if you find some error.

Comment: Your script does not really test whether a password is strong (because there's no such thing as a *strong password*, only a *strong password generation method*), and it gives bad advice: special characters do not make a password stronger.

Comment: Additionally, there are a number of functional bugs, the most serious one being the script will not run as desired if you run it in a directory with single-character file names.

Comment: @Gilles, I see the criticism of you first comment, but I do not understand that of the second comment.  I think the script is independent of the file names in the current directory, it does not read or write any file. Please explain. Or are you thinking of redirection?

Comment: @sudodus Run `touch a; rm b` and compare what your script has to say about `12345678Aa_` and `12345678Ab_`. It labels the second one as weak because the first grep becomes `grep a`. Then run `touch b`, change `&>/dev/null` to `>/dev/null` (it's hardly ever a good idea to ignore error messages), and observe the error reported by grep.

Comment: @Gilles, I made a completely new shellscript, using my new knowledge about passwords. If you think this shellscript is meaningful (maybe with improvements), I will keep it, otherwise I will delete it (in order to avoid confusion in the important field of security). Thanks for helping me and other people understand more about passwords :-) Thanks also to muru for telling us about `cracklib-check` :-)

Comment: You've fixed the worst functional bugs by double-quoting variable expansions. Beyond that, it's a lot of code and it isn't clear to me what the goal of your script is. I can't offer a full code review, but you might try [codereview.se].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68580/discussion-between-sudodus-and-gilles).

Comment: @Gilles, one of the things I try to do with the shellscript is help `cracklib-check` perform better.

Answer (score 1):

```
td -d "[:alnum:]"
```

works for me:

```
$> echo '123§45!67M89(0' | tr -d  "[:alnum:]"
§!(
```

You can use it like

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a password : "
read password
LEN=$(echo ${#password})

if [ $LEN -lt 10 ]; then
    echo "$password is smaller than 10 characters"
else
    if [ $(echo $password | tr -d "[:alnum:]" | wc -w) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$password is a weak password"
    else
        echo "$password is a strong password"
    fi
fi                                                                                                                      echo
```

`wc -w` counts the words.

- So if you remove all `alnum` and the word count is `0` => true => weak password
- if the word count is `1` (or more if spaces are used) => false => strong password

Comment: I added syntax highlighting. Makes scripts easier to read.

Comment: Oh didn't see that. Just copy pasted my answer in again ;) changed it again.. Though usually this is done automatically isn't it?

Comment: depending on tags. If the question were tagged bash, for example, everything would be highlighted as a bash script... But the question isn't really about bash.

Comment: You've overcomplicated things even more with the use of `wc`, you've also changed the logic since for example spaces no longer count as making a password “strong”, and you've kept many bugs from the original such as the treatment of `a * b` as input.

Answer (score -3):

I found the correct script and it works:

```bsh
echo -n "Enter a password : "
read password

LEN=$(echo ${#password})

if [ $LEN -lt 10 ]; then

       echo "$password is smaller than 10 characters"
else
     if  [ -z `echo $password | tr -d '[:alpha:]' | tr -d '[:upper:]' | tr -d '[:lower:]' ` ]; then
        echo "$password is a weak password"
     else
        echo "$password is a strong password"
     fi
fi
echo
```

Comment: This does still not work for me -> returns allways "strong password"

Answer (score -3):

Finally, the following script that i wrote, solved my problem:

```bsh
echo -n "Enter a password : "
read password

LEN=$(echo ${#password})

if [ $LEN -lt 10 ]; then

   echo "$password is smaller than 10 characters"

else

 if  [ -z `echo $password | tr -d '[:alpha:]' | tr -d '[:upper:]' | tr -d '[:lower:]' ` ] || [ -z `echo $password | tr -d '[:upper:]' | tr -d '[:digit:]' `] || [ -z `echo $password | tr -d '[:lower:]' | tr -d '[:digit:]' `] ; then

    echo "$password is a weak password"

 else

    echo "$password is a strong password"

 fi

fi

echo
```

Thanks for your responses guys!

Comment: I suggest you read Gilles's answer. Your script still has massive issues.