# On 18.04 i cannot type @ (symbol) with the screen keyboard

Tags: keyboard, screen

After a fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04 i cannot use @ on the screen keyboard.The on screen keyboard is very useful for people that they have to use only mouse for typing.Instead of @ i have a 2. I use ubuntu 16.04 without any problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug that affects the on screen keyboard in 18.04.

A similar bug also affects the on screen keyboard in 17.10. (18.04 and 17.10 use different packages for the on screen keyboard, but they surprisingly have the same problem!)

Both bugs only occur if you are using Xorg; if you use Wayland, the bug is not there.

Therefore, one option for you might be to use Wayland instead of Xorg.

Because 18.04 uses a different package for the on screen keyboard, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983666/caribou-on-screen-keyboard-shift-key-not-working/989247#989247) fix I had posted for 17.10 no longer works.

You should also up-vote [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/135#note_115965) Gnome bug to let the devs know that you are impacted. The more people that express interest, the more likely they will be inclined to provide a fix.