# How do I force users to use strong password ? (Ubuntu 18.04 Server)

Tags: 18.04, security

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Server. How do I force users to use strong password ?

I already set SSH and remove root login.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StrongPasswords and https://askubuntu.com/questions/244115/how-do-i-enforce-a-password-complexity-policy

Comment: @Rinzwind; thanks but What I want is not 'how to generate passwords' but how to prevent users to manually set weak passwords;

Comment: See the link: the accepted answer tells you.